# JS array to PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string containing a Javascript array the next way:

```
$array = "var Array = [
             { 'a' : 'val1', 'b': 1},
             { 'a' : 'val2', 'b': 2}
];";
```

How can I convert this string to a PHP array in the next structure:

```
$array[0] => array('a' => 'val1', 'b' => 1)
$array[1] => array('a' => 'val2', 'b' => 2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely look into using json to communicate code between php and js. However, I don't know what you want to use this code for, so this is does what you want (as a general rule, you don't want to use that):

```
<?php

$str = 'var Array = [
             {"a": "val1", "b": 1},
             {"a": "val2", "b": 2}
];';

$matches = array();
preg_match("/^(var\s+)*([A-Za-z0-9_\.]+)\s*=\s*([^;]+);$/", $str, $matches);

print "<pre>";
var_dump($matches);
print "</pre>";

$array = json_decode($matches[3], true);

print "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

Also note that I had to replace the single quotes with double quotes for this to work, I have no idea why I had to do that.

If you say why you need this, you might get a little more help.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/v8js.executestring.php would probably better than regex :P

Comment: @Esailija Post it as an answer.... or is it ironic? :) But it seems as a good solution... why the `:P`. You are confusing!

Answer (score 6):

This will **Help**:

Example :

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

The above example will output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: How so?  There is no single array list. And changing the problem domain from a JS expression to a fictional and flat JSON string makes this a non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON for this.

Please look carefully at the differences I made, JSON syntax is much stricter than javascript object initializer syntax.

```
$array = '[
             { "a" : "val1", "b": 1},
             { "a" : "val2", "b": 2}
]';

$array = json_decode($array, true );

print_r($array);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => val1
            [b] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => val2
            [b] => 2
        )

)

*/
```